# Динамическое Ajax окно

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет. Решил заняться внедрением Ajax форм на свой сайт, но не хватает не много знаний, которые пригодились бы при создание. (Поисковики не помогли.).

Хотелось бы узнать оптимальное создание форм на ajax, каким образом его можно сделать?
В некоторых примерах видел, что с помощью jquery создают окно, а в него вставляют iFrame с формой, но мне кажется, что это не удобный способ, так как для каждого окна нужно создавать новую форму в отдельном файле.

На некоторых популярных сайтах, видел, что там используется исключительно JS (Промежутком в js встречается html разметка), но как этот способ реализовывается - у меня вызывает затруднение.

Может быть, у кого-нибудь есть наброски ajax форм, которыми могли бы поделиться или же рассказать мне, как происходит это в процессе написания кода.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вообщем к примеру создадим функцию `load_in_ajax_form()` и передадим ей параметр URL, потом посредством ajax загрузим этот URL в форму

```
//index.html
function load_in_ajax_form(url){
var response = $.post(url);
$('#form').html(response);
}
<div id="form"></div>
<button onclick="load_in_ajax_form('http://mysite.ru/form.html')"></button>
```

Только если Вы будете использовать скрипты в загружаемой странице, подключите их к в ту страницу где находиться ajax окно.

UPD не правильно вас понял, тогда выдирайте значение полей в форме и передавайте их посредством `ajax`

Comment: Не правильно похоже.

Comment: Ну я так на бум написал, но смысл думаю понятен, а правильно написать, это дело пяти минут

Comment: Смысл понятен. Спасибо. Не плохо. Но все же, на самой странице нужно создавать формы - это не удобно, так как те же формы нужно использовать и на других страницах, а при редактирования формы придется править все страницы.